# Certificate for Client Authentication

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, fastapi, hypercorn

I need your help.
I want to generate a certificate for a client for authorization on my api.

In my use case, I have an API that is hosted with python hypercorn and fastapi. Then I have multiple clients (also python (httpx)) that should request data from this api. For authentication between the client and the server, I want to use certificates. I want to provide the client with a certificate with which it can authorize itself with the server.

For generating the certificates i used this instruction: https://www.makethenmakeinstall.com/2014/05/ssl-client-authentication-step-by-step/

What did I do wrong, or how can I implement my use case?

server:

```py
async def main():
    config = Config.from_mapping(dict(
        worker_class='trio',
        certfile='server.cer', 
        keyfile='server.key', 
        verify_mode=VerifyMode.CERT_REQUIRED,
        bind=f"0.0.0.0:{8000}"))

    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        nursery.start_soon(serve, app, config)
```

client:

```py
import httpx

res = httpx.get("https://localhost:8000/", verify=True, cert=("client.cer", "client.key"))
res
```

When I execute the request in the client I get the following error:
`ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1123)`

Comment: The server authentication failed, not the client authentication.

Answer (score 0):

let's simplify how certificates work.
certificates used for authentication and authorization and this is what you're exactly doing in your case. your backend-server has its own certificate, and your client has his own certificate. your applications is set to recognize each other using these certificates and you're doing it in a great way.

but certificates are vulnerable and can be created locally, so I myself can create a certificate that says that I'm facebook or google. and here is the validation's role come; a well know authority that's already implemented in all browsers and OS - and we call it CA for a certification authority - signs your certificates, so when your server send its cert to a client, the client's browser would recognize the signature and tells you that the certificate is valid.

in your case here you have a self signed certificate, which means that for development purpose you've signed your cert by yourself "instead of the recognized CAs".

Overcoming such an issue would be in two ways.

1. you disable the validation in your code and in your client side as well. suits for development purpose or intra network.
2. sign your certificate and your client's certificate with a recognized authority like digicert, and add your CA in your trust-store.